# Uwsgi - Socket file or URL

Tags: linux, debian, uwsgi, socket

I was installing UWSGI and it looks like for the socket I can specify either a URL and port or instead I can specify a socket location file.

I was wondering if anyone can tell me what the difference is between these two, and if one is preferable to the other.

Thank you.

Comment: This has a pretty good answer already. Duplicate?

http://serverfault.com/questions/195328/unix-socket-vs-tcp-ip-hostport

Answer (score 1):

You can run uwsgi to listen to a TCP/IP port, for example uwsgi --http :80 , if you change it to listen to a Unix socket (for ex: uwsgi --socket :8000 ) then this is local only, no web service (TCP/IP) is exposed to the Internet and you have to put a web server like nginx in front of uwsgi as 'proxy' that can get the http requests from the outside world (see https://gist.github.com/evildmp/3094281 for a django example instead of Flask)